# Write timestap in css url param with github actions

Tags: github-actions

I'm new to GitHub Actions. This is some powerful stuff. I used to deploy my sites old-school via FTP transmit.

Is it somehow possible to change the URL parameter on a CSS file on each deployment with GitHub actions, to invalidate the browser caching on each deploy:

```
<link href="/theme/css/style.min.css?version={{ add timestamp or git hash or something }}">
```

I don't know where to look. This line is in a ordinary php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with sed replacement:

```
❯ echo '<link href="/theme/css/style.min.css?version=VERSION">' > example.php
❯ echo '<link href="/theme/css/style2.min.css?version=VERSION">' >> example.php
❯ cat example.php
<link href="/theme/css/style.min.css?version=VERSION">
<link href="/theme/css/style2.min.css?version=VERSION">
❯ sed -i "s/?version=VERSION/?version=$(date +%s)/g" example.php
❯ cat example.php
<link href="/theme/css/style.min.css?version=1645169164">
<link href="/theme/css/style2.min.css?version=1645169164">
```

In the workflow yaml, just write:

```
run: sed -i "s/?version=VERSION/?version=$(date +%s)/g" example.php
```

Comment: Wow. Elegant. So `example.php` will be the path to the file relative to root?

Comment: @KSPR Yes, exactly.